# Align cells in center of row in tableview objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm android developer, i have some dynamic tableview. It looks like this in android

[image]

but on ios project it looks this way:

[image]

As you see the cells are aligned to the left edge

How can i center the cells in ios, like in android version?

I would post the code, but the

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is huge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need implement

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                    layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
    insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
```

Comment: https://github.com/keighl/KTCenterFlowLayout 
i will try this solution, see if this works, then try your's thanks

Comment: I marked your answer as correct, but i used the https://github.com/keighl/KTCenterFlowLayout

he wrapped the UICollectionViewFlowLayout, nice solution. I hope it will work properly on all platforms, ios versions,devices